# Javascript and Chrome - Get identification

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have developed a site for use on my company's intranet. You can not access the site from outside of the network.

Asking users to log-in pretty much means they won't use it as logging in is seen as cumbersome. I am trying to find the most seamless way of grabbing some identification.

I used Javascript and Chrome to develop the site. I would like to have a way to grab a computer name or windows user name or something that will uniquely identify the user. A chrome extension would work.

I understand ethical issues with an application on the internet doing this, but this is for internal use only.

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this with Javascript/Chrome? An extension would work.

Comment: If your workplace permits social media, you could consider using something like Facebook Connect as an easy way to implement one-click authentication. However... if your coworkers are too apathetic to type in a password, I don't see why they'd be willing to click a button. Good luck!

Comment: What if I store a file on each computer in the C:\ drive called computername.txt. Then I could use javascript to open the file to get the computer name. Or I could store a file in c:\Users\username\My Documents with each users username. Then I could load it with javascript from the My Documents folder which should be unique to the user logged in. How does that sound?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible to read files from the user's computer without first having the user choose it with a file input. Otherwise you could read any file on the user's computer (passwords, email, etc). However, since it sounds like you have access to the computers in question, you might want to consider logging in on behalf of each user and just remembering them with a cookie.

Comment: But when a user goes to the page, how will the application know who it should log in as?

Comment: If you store the user's identity in a cookie as part of your log in process, you can access that value as many times as you want until the cookie expires or the user clears the browser's cookies. This is how Facebook, Google, etc remember who you are after you restart your computer. Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie to understand what cookies are and how they work, then google or search stack overflow for a tutorial explaining how to work with your own cookies using javascript.

Comment: Cookies are looking like they will do the trick. Thanks.